# modelForm crispy formhelper and choices list datepicker not showing

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, form-helpers

I've searched through Stackoverflow for this and cannot find an answer.

I am trying to render a ModelForm using crispy forms and FormHelper to help me lay it out nicely.
Everything was working fine when I was using the forms.Form library. but the main problem now is that the date picker and the choices field no longer have a dropdown list with the datepicker or the

So this is my forms.py file:

```
CITIES= (("London","London"), ("Istanbul","Istanbul"), ("Cape Town","Cape Town"))

class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Items
        itemName = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'item name'}))
        ...
        date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),required=False)
        location =forms.ChoiceField(choices=CITIES, required=False)
        
        fields = ['itemName', 'date', 'location']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EntryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'itemName',
             ...
             Row(
                 Column('date', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                 Column('location', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                 css_class='form-row'
             ),
        
             Submit('submit','Submit')
         )
```

My template file looks like this:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    
    {% block content %}
    
    <h1>Entry Form</h1>
    <br>
      {% crispy form %}
    <br>
   
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think I see an error: you've defined your fields as part of the `EntryForm.Meta` class, and they should instead be part of the `EntryForm` class - not the `Meta` class.

Comment: In the end, I've had to solve this by using the `model.Forms` class and not `models.ModelForm`.
Just out of interest, however, on what line do you see the error and how would you change it?

Comment: Just posted it as an answer so that I could format the code correctly. Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, can you please be more specific with how you fixed the issue? I am encountering the same problem

Comment: hi @WonderSteve, 
Why don't you post your problem? My question above was edited to include the fix.

The original line for my class entry was `class EntryForm(forms.Form):`

I changed this to:

`class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):`

Your error may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% certain if this is the issue, but I think you might just need to shift the fields to the EntryForm class, like so:

```
class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Fields should go here, not under the Meta class:
    itemName = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'item name'}))
    ...
    date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),required=False)
    location =forms.ChoiceField(choices=CITIES, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Items    
        fields = ['itemName', 'date', 'location']
```

Comment: Thank you @YellowShark.
I did have it set up like this too. The problem is not the form not working. 
The issue was getting the date picker and the ChoiceField to work correctly using `django-crispy-forms` 
I will update how I solved this using the Forms class later tonight hopefully.